# Characterization of Fourier multiplier for $p=q=1$. Grafakos. Classical Fourier Analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Hello again. I have some doubts in this theorem. I am trying to see all the details to understand it. I have the following

equation 2.5.13 is:

$<g,f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u>\to <g,\mu>$.

Affirmation. $<g,f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u>=<u,\tilde{f}_{\epsilon_{k}}*g>$

Proof:$<g,f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u>:
=\int g(x)(f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u)(x)dx\\
=\int g(x)(\int f_{\epsilon_{k}}(y)u(x-y)dy)dx\\
=\int g(x)
(\int\tilde{f}_{\epsilon_{k}}(-y)u(x-y)dy)dx\\
=\int g(x)
(\int\tilde{f}_{\epsilon_{k}}(y)u(x+y)dy)dx\\
=\int g(z-y)
(\int\tilde{f}_{\epsilon_{k}}(y)u(z)dy)dz\\
=\int u(z)
(\int\tilde{f}_{\epsilon_{k}}(y)g(z-y)dy)dz\\
=\int u(z)
(\tilde{f}_{\epsilon_{k}}*g)(z)dz\\
=<u,\tilde{f}_{\epsilon_{k}}*g>$.

Affirmation 2. $<u,\tilde{f}_{\epsilon_{k}}*g>=<u,f_{\epsilon_{k}}*g>$

proof: Similary to affirmation 1.

Exists a subsequence $f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u\subset f_{\epsilon}*u$ such that 
$f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u\to \mu$, for some $\mu\in \mathcal{M}$ (Borel finite measure).

Here my main question.
$f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u,\ \mu$ are in $(C_{0}(R^n))^{\ast}$ right?, i.e. they are continuous linear functionals i.e. $f_{\epsilon_{k}}(g)\to \mu(g)$ for any $g\in C_{0}(R^n)$. Right?

$f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u\to \mu$ weak star convergence.

This is, $\| f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u-\mu\|_{\mathcal{M}}\to 0$. Right?

$\| f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u-\mu\|_{\mathcal{M}}:=\sup_{g\in C_{0}(R^n)}\left|\int g(x)[(f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u)(x)-\mu(x)]dx\right|$ ??

For this context, what is the norm $\|\mu\|_{\mathcal{M}}$?

Why in Grafakos, $f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u\to \mu$ weak star convergence implies $\lim_{k} \int g(x)(f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u)(x)dx=\int g(x)d\mu(x)$?

pd: $d\mu(x):=\mu(x)dx$?

actualization 1:

Theorem (Riesz Representation) If $X$ locally compact space and $\mu\in \mathcal{M}(X)$, define $F_{\mu}:C_{0}(X)\to \mathcal{F}$ by $F_{\mu}=\int f d\mu$. 
Then $F_{u}\in (C_{0})(X))^{\ast}$ and the map $\mu\mapsto F_{\mu}$ is an isometric isomorphism of $\mathcal{M}(X)$ onto $(C_{0}(X))^{\ast}$.

Affirmation: $L^1(R^n)$ can be identified as a subspace of $\mathcal{M}(R^n)$ (finite borel measure) by the isometry $f(x)\to f(x)dx$, $dx$ leebesgue measure.
This affirmation, appears in Stein, Singular Integrals and differenciability properties.

Now, as $f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u\in L^1$ then $f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u dx \in \mathcal{M}(R^n)=(C_{0}(R^n))^{\ast}$ and $\mu \in\mathcal{M}(R^n)=(C_{0}(R^n))^{\ast}$. 
therefore by Riesz Representation, $f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u,\ \mu$ are identified by $\int g(x)(f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u)(x)d\mu$ and $\int g(x)d\mu$ for any $g\in C_{0}(R^n)$.
It is correct?

As $\lim_{k} f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u=\mu$, *-weak convergence,  for the above, $\lim_{k} \int g(x)(f_{\epsilon_{k}}*u)(x)dx=\int g(x)d\mu(x)$.

It is correct?